# Difference between a C++/CLI ref class and a C# class

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I had read that the C++/CLI `ref class` was the equivalent to a C# class. However, I'm seeing a difference between `this` in each class.

EDIT: I obtained `this` from Visual Studio 2010's locals. (Also, I noted a difference at compile time when doing exact same cast - the C++/CLI class gave an error stating it could not convert Object^ to MyClass^, whereas casting with the C# class creates no errors at compile time).

**C# class:**

```
namespace MyNamespace
{

   public class MyClass
   {    
       public MyClass()
           {
               //Do something
           }
   }
}
```

`this` = **MyNamespace.MyClass**  (What I expect and want!)

---

**C++/CLI `ref class`:**

```
namespace MyNamespace
{

   public ref class MyClass
   {    
       public:
           MyClass::MyClass()
           {
               //Do something
           }
   }
}
```

`this` = **System::Object^** (*Not* what I expected or want!!)

---

I would expect `this` to be like the C# example, which states that `this` is of type `MyClass`. However, the C++/CLI ref class states it is of type `Object`.. Which is definitely NOT what I want.
(This makes it difficult in various situations, such as casting in a C++ function).

So my question is (two part):

a) why are these classes behaving differently with `this`?

b) how do I get my C++/CLI ref class to have the correct type in `this`??

Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: How do you check what type `this` is?

Comment: You didn't provide any relevant code that shows us how you used `this`

Comment: @svick: From Visual Studio 2010's locals

Comment: @Yochai Timmer: I updated my question to reflect that I obtained `this` from looking at the locals in VS.

Comment: How about adding actual code for that? For example you could print to the console. Debuggers sometimes behave strangely.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I added to my question that there is a difference at compilation when casting as well.

Comment: @developer: have you tried actually emitting the Type?  The debugger is probably just displaying the base type.

Comment: I still want to see actual code.

Comment: @developer, when breaking in the constructor of your class VS shows `this` as `MyNamespace::MyClass^`. `System::Console::WriteLine(this->GetType());` outputs `MyNamespace.MyClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing in the debugger is the name of the base class - in this case `Object^`.  Change the base class of `MyClass` to something else and you will see what I mean.

[image: Locals window]

Note that the right most column displays the type.

Comment: Mine looks slightly different (only two levels.. `this` and `System::Object^` But you're right, the type is different. It reads `MyNamespace::MyClass^`. But unfortunately I'm still getting the incorrect type when attempting to cast.. but I guess that is not a problem with `this` though.